# datetime order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a website which contains news data and I want show the most updated data by time,
I have field column_time contains 8 data. Why when I use this SQL:

```
select * from table_name order by waktu desc
```

is the result this:

```
28 Jan 2013 | 15:36:47
28 Jan 2013 | 15:30:48
27 Jan 2013 | 21:38:36
27 Jan 2013 | 21:38:32
27 Jan 2013 | 21:38:29
11 Feb 2013 | 20:41:05
11 Feb 2013 | 20:40:37
11 Feb 2013 | 20:36:11
```

and not this?

```
11 Feb 2013 | 20:41:05
11 Feb 2013 | 20:40:37
11 Feb 2013 | 20:36:11
28 Jan 2013 | 15:36:47
28 Jan 2013 | 15:30:48
27 Jan 2013 | 21:38:36
27 Jan 2013 | 21:38:32
27 Jan 2013 | 21:38:29
```

Comment: what is the data type for this column

Comment: If you want to order by, why are you ordering by waktu? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, can you tell us what is the data type of the "waktu" column?

Comment: @Satya : type data is varchar(22) coz i using php date("d M Y | H:i:s") at waktu column

Answer (score 3):

The column is sorted like **character** data, type `varchar` or `text`.
You probably want to use `timestamp` or `datetime` as data type, depending on your secret RDBMS.

Comment: thx for answers, but i didnt talk about the type data, if i using the datetime this absolutly can order by correctly. I talk about field(text/varchar) which is contains date but cant order by correctly. Any idea?

Comment: @DonnyAgus: Well, **I** am talking about the data type, because you get your desired sort order with the proper data type. Also please tell us the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to order by latest record *(not just time)* ([DEMO - Converting to DATETIME](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8718))

```
Select * from table_name
Order by convert(Datetime,replace(your_column,' | ',' ')) desc
```

***OR*** if you just need to *order by time* regardless of date then use; (Also you can convert to Time if you are on above sql-server 2008)

```
Order by convert(Datetime, substring(your_column,
         charindex('|',your_column,1)+2,len(your_column))) desc
```